# Multiple DNS A record for one machine

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address, shared-hosting, http-status-code-404

I saw [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/56539/dns-multiple-a-records-or-1-a-record-and-lots-of-cnames) post but it doesn't really address my situation. I am trying to add a second Address record for the same IP address but for some reason I am constantly getting a 404 bounce from `dsnextgen.com`??

Is it possible to set more then one Address record for one shared machine? If so any ideas why I'm getting a 404 bounce from `dsnextgen.com`?

Comment: What is `dsnextgen.com` to you?

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with HTTP status codes. If you get 404, then it's the web server responding, so you ARE reaching the server. It may be webserver hostname mapping that are not properly configured for you?

Comment: @BartDeVos I have no idea what `dsnextgen.com` is and no idea why it's in the way...

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs The 1st address I configured seemed to work no problem. But when I add a second it never resolves. The hosting is a generic CPanel fronted shared jobby. When setting up the account it asked me to specify the site's name. However, my domains are hosted elsewhere. What gets me is why my 1st address had no problem but the second one just doesn't work... I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is open to interpretation, but it sounds like you may be adding a second domain to a hosting account, but you haven't actually configured that domain name to point to the correct IP of the hosting provider your using (or it points to the right IP, but the web server doesnt know what to do with that 'host header'/virtual domain... You need to specify the domain name you want the webserver to 'listen for', and it will determine what to do based on the domain name used to goto the site. See virtual hosts or host headers... I could be wrong, but might be worth checking..

Comment: Hmm you might be onto something there re: the domain the virtual host listens for....