# Is this zone file correct? Just to point a subdomain to another machine

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am running bind9 on my home machine and hosting several zone files. This is working nicely and I am running various web services.

I now want to host a web service on an external machine (a Linode), and would like to verify that my host file looks correct;

In this example `1.2.3.4` is my home machine, and `100.101.102.103` is my Linode.

```
TTL 86400

example.com.     IN  SOA   ns.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                        7               ; serial number
                        28800           ; Refresh
                        7200            ; Retry
                        864000          ; Expire
                        86400 )         ; Min TTL

@           IN  NS      ns.example.com.

@           IN  A       1.2.3.4
ns1         IN  A       1.2.3.4
test        IN  A       100.101.102.103
www         IN  A       100.101.102.103
```

I want www.example.com and test.example.com to be hosted on my Linode, which will not be running bind, only a web server.

Thank you!

Darren

Answer (score 2):

Where is your `A` record for ns.example.com?

The debate about using `CNAME`s or multiple `A` records is up to you: [DNS - Multiple A records or 1 A record and lots of CNAMEs?](https://serverfault.com/q/56539/3139)

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Requests for www.example.com and test.example.com will be directed to 100.101.102.103.

Comment: Appreciate it :)